# Can touch spells, like cure wounds, be cast through a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, familiars

If my character chooses Ritual Caster for his 1st-level Variant Human feat and gains *find familiar*, can he cast *cure wounds* via the familiar due to it being a touch spell?

Also, can he move the familiar to an ally and cast *cure wounds* in the same turn?

Comment: Can you clarify the "can he cast cure wounds via the familiar due to it being a touch spell" part? What class the character is? Do you ask if the familiar gives you the Cure Wounds spell itself?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Using a familiar to deliver a touch attack with the Ready action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50310) in terms of working out the action economy of delivering a touch spell through a familiar, pointing out that the Wizard can ready the spell to cast on the familiar's turn so it doesn't have to end a turn next to an enemy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Find Familiar* says that:

> when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it.

So yes, since it's a touch-range spell your familiar can deliver *Cure Wounds* for you. The player casts it using his action, the familiar delivers it using its reaction.

The moving bit is a little trickier. *Find Familiar* says that

> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands. In combat, it rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn.

This means that the familiar will have to move next to the person you want to heal on its turn to be ready to deliver the spell when you cast it on your turn. It won't be able to move with its reaction, and there isn't a way for you to move it on your turn. (Well, there are some spells you could use to push it around, but not on the same turn as casting *Cure Wounds*.)

If your turn is before its turn, the best thing to do is probably to Ready your *Cure Wounds* with a trigger along the lines of "When my familiar is next to Victor the Victim, I will cast *Cure Wounds*." Then, on your familiar's turn, it moves next to Victor the Victim, triggering your reaction to cast *Cure Wounds*, and then your familiar uses its reaction to deliver *Cure Wounds* to Victor. (Using a reaction on your own turn is unusual but perfectly allowable.) The only problem with this strategy is that if your concentration is broken between your turn and your familiar's turn, you will lose the *Cure Wounds* spell, costing you the action and the spell slot you used to cast it.

Comment: @DaFluid not exactly. When a reaction trigger occurs (e.g. Opportunity attack) you can choose to take that reaction and lose the spell or pass on the reaction and keep the spell "primed"