# Can an Order of Scribes wizard cast 'touch' spells through Manifest Mind?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, spellcasting

If I wanted to cast *bestow curse* via the spectral mind from the Order of Scribes' Manifest Mind ability on an enemy adjacent to it, would I be able to?

Manifest Mind lets you cast spells 'as if you were in the spectral mind's space', but I'm not quite sure how that interacts with touch spells, given the mind itself is "intangible" (or if that even matters, since technically the spell isn't saying the mind is the one casting it, and my wizard 50 feet away *definitely* can't touch that creature).

(Note that the language of casting through Manifest Mind is not the same as the language used for [*find familiar*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70200/15614), which explicitly specifies touch spells.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes, you can.

The [Order of Scribes wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes)'s [Manifest Mind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ManifestMind-2986096) feature description reads (TCoE, p. 78):

> Whenever you cast a wizard spell on your turn, you can cast it **as if you were in the spectral mind’s space**, instead of your own, using its senses.

The phrase "as if you were in the spectral mind's space" indicates that for the purposes of casting the spell, you just treat the situation as though you were in that space, instead of the space the Scribes wizard is actually in.

If I were actually in the Spectral Mind's space, would I be able to cast this spell? If yes, then I can cast the spell from my actual space just as if I were in the Mind's space.

Answer (score -2):

The description of the [Scribes wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes)'s [Manifest Mind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ManifestMind-2986096) feature reads (TCoE, p. 78):

> While manifested, the spectral mind can hear and see, and it has
> darkvision with a range of 60 feet. The mind can telepathically share
> with you what it sees and hears (no action required).

I don't think touch would be included. In addition, the feature description also states:

> It can pass through creatures but not objects.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Could you elaborate on your answer to more directly address the question? How does the quoted text relate to casting spells with a range of "touch"?