# How to use Find Familiar 'spell delivery' aggressively without getting the familiar killed

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

So I've decided to choose the Arcane Trickster path for my Rogue. One interesting spell I saw was [Find Familiar](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Familiar#content). The familiar can't attack but it can 'deliver' spells.

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar
>   can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must
>   be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the
>   spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use
>   your attack modifier for the roll.

If I understand this correctly the spell is cast in the turn of the rogue and immediately delivered through the familiar as a reaction.

This means that the familiar has to be standing next to the enemy before its the rogue's turn and can only move away on its own turn. Leaving the enemy time for an attack. Since all familiars have a very low AC (13 max) and no HP to speak of, I do not understand how I can keep my familiar alive in combat.

Comment: There are at least 4 different questions in here. Try to break it up a bit and ask them separately. You seem to have problems with 1) Familiar action economy 2) Familiar turn order 3) Choice of defensive spells 4) Combat tactics for protecting familiar. The 3 &4 might still be unanswerable unless you state a very specific goal to achieve (e.g. how to move familiar out of range or how to boost familiar's defensive stats) and a clear situation (a combat with this character, this familiar, this kind of spell against this-sort of enemies).

Comment: Sorry, only now I see that this question is actually a duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50310/using-a-familiar-to-deliver-a-touch-attack?rq=1 I didn't see it before. Can this question be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: No problem! There you go.